# Problemin install scikit-image

Tags: python

I have python 3.6.4 on Windows 10. I am trying to install scikit-image by
'pip install scikit-image', But I am getting the follow error saying '\site-packages\scikit_image-0.13.1-py3.6.egg-info\installed-files.txt'

Can you please tell me how can I fix this issue? Thank you

```
  Running setup.py install for scikit-image ... done
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 922, in install
    with open(inst_files_path, 'w') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\shared\\python36_64\\Lib\\site-packages\\scikit_image-0.13.1-py3.6.egg-info\\installed-files.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python/Scripts,
in command prompt,
try: easy_install scikit-image